# How to add a quantity value in an already existing value

Tags: php, html

I have an add to cart code in php. I created a code that when the user select an already existing product in the cart the quantity of the existing product and the inputted new quantity will be added to each other

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pos";
    $id=$name =$price=$quantity_order=$old_quantity_order = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];                 
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $quantity_order = $_POST['quantity_order'];
        $subtotal = $price * $quantity_order;
    }
    $check="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = $id";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$check) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_row($sql))
    {
        $old_quantity_order=$res['quantity_order'];
    }               
        $new_quantity_order =$quantity_order +  $old_quantity_order;
        $up = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE cart SET quantity_order='$new_quantity_order' WHERE id=$id");
    }
    else {

        $sql =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO cart (id,name, price,quantity_order,subtotal)
        VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$price','$quantity_order','$subtotal')");
    }

        header("Location:pos.php")
```

I tried to fetch the existing quantity in the database and rename it as $old_quantity_order and to be added on the inputed quantity which is $quantity_order.

But  the only value that enter my database is the value of $quantity_order, the $old_quantity_order is 0.

This is the form I used to add a quantity_order to the cart.

```
<div class="form-group">        
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"/>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity_order" placeholder="quantity"  min="1" max="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" formaction="add_to_cart.php" id="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart"  OnClick="return mess();">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="process" formaction="process_frompos.php" value="Process"></a>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please help me sir to correct my code,it's alright even if it take some time. I just created this code by merging and editing the sources that I found so Im not sure what my errors are.

Comment: the $old_quantity_order += $res['quantity_order'] still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below code and see if you get any [PHP Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel).

```
$servername = "localhost";
//it is BAD practise to connect to your DB as root. 
$username = "pubuser";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pos";
$id = $price = $quantity_order = $old_quantity_order = 0;
$name = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//
// $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is so common, and I don't like it as it's 
// not a clear check. Intead check that the array is populated. 
//
if (\is_array($_POST) && \count($_POST) > 0) {

    // Id is usually a digit number.  
    // So force to type. NEVER trust user input!
    $id = (int) $_POST['id'];

    $name = $_POST['name'];     
    // $price may be a float or an int?             
    $price = (float) $_POST['price'];
    $quantity_order = (int) $_POST['quantity_order'];
    $subtotal = $price * $quantity_order;
}

//
// So what happens here, if POST has not been set?
//

// Only grab the rows you need from the database:
$check="SELECT quantity_order FROM cart WHERE id = $id";

// 1) Mysqli_error needs the connection variable.
// 2) Errors shold be logged to an error log, NOT thrown to output.  
// 3) USE PREPARED STATEMENTS
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$check) or error_log(__LINE__." : ".mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

    // Because you're calling only one row, you don't need to loop it. 
    $res = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

    $new_quantity_order = $quantity_order +  $res['quantity_order'];

    $up = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE cart SET quantity_order =
          ".(int)$new_quantity_order." WHERE id = ".$id );
}
else {
    // Numerical column values in SQL do not need to be encased in quotes 
    // and this slows down transactions.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (id, name, price, quantity_order, subtotal)
    VALUES ( ".$id.", '".$name."', ".$price.", ".(int)$quantity_order." ,".$subtotal.")";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or error_log(__LINE__." : ".mysqli_error($conn));
}

    // your header needs to have a semicolon ; at the end. 
    header("Location:pos.php");
    // header Locations MUST then be followed by an exit/die statement. 
    exit;
```

---

## Useful links:

- [INSERT on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [A guide for using PHP Prepared Statements (PDO)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)
- [How to Use/Find/Read PHP Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)
- [PHP Best Practises](https://phpbestpractices.org/)

Comment: Sir, it doesn't have any php error. But it still doesn't add the value of the quantities, it only read the new inputted quantity

Comment: try `error_log(print_r($_POST,true));` near the top of your script. What does it show you?

Comment: It doesnt show anything, the values are still added to the cart and headed to the next php ,which is the pos.php. But the quantity still doesn't add up.

Comment: Then that means your POSTed data is empty. The problem is not on this page but is on however you POST the data to the page. Please update your question.

Comment: Do you mean sir, that the error is on the previous php file? And why do I need to update the question?

Comment: @Vanie update your question with the details of the page SENDING the `$_POST` data. Because this posted data appears to be empty,this is why your code is not working as you'd like.